# ABC-flow integration and visualization

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

I am working my way through the book "A First Course in Computational Fluid Dynamics". One of the exercises is to integrate the [ABC-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%E2%80%93Beltrami%E2%80%93Childress_flow) equations using Runge-Kutta and visualize it.

Here is my naive implementation in Python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
```

This implements the ABC-flow computation:

```
def abc_flow( t, p ):
    x = p[ 0 ]
    y = p[ 1 ]
    z = p[ 2 ]

    u = A * np.sin( z ) + C * np.cos( y )
    v = B * np.sin( x ) + A * np.cos( z )
    w = C * np.sin( y ) + B * np.cos( x )

    return np.array( [ u, v, w ] )
```

This is the 4th order Runge-Kutta implementation (I know I could use a ready-made solver, this is just for learning purposes):

```
def runge_kutta( f, p, t ):
    k0 = f( t, p )
    k1 = f( t + dt * 0.5, p + ( dt * 0.5 ) * k0 )
    k2 = f( t + dt * 0.5, p + ( dt * 0.5 ) * k1 )
    k3 = f( t + dt, p + dt * k2 )

    p_next = p + ( dt / 6.0 ) * ( k0 + 2 * k1 + 2 * k2 + k3 )

    return p_next
```

These are the parameters as suggested in the book:

```
L = 2 * np.pi

A = 1
B = 1
C = 0.65
```

Finally, this is the integration loop:

```
N = 100000
dt = 0.01

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = np.array( [ 3, np.pi, np.pi ] )

    x = [ p[ 0 ] ]
    y = [ p[ 1 ] ]
    z = [ p[ 2 ] ]

    for _ in range( N ):
        p = runge_kutta( abc_flow, p, 0 )

        x.append( p[ 0 ] )
        y.append( p[ 1 ] )
        z.append( p[ 2 ] )
```

The book asks to plot the particle position from each side of the box, which I have implemented as follows:

```
    fig = plt.figure( tight_layout=True )
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec( 3, 1 )

    ax = fig.add_subplot( gs[0, 0] )
    ax.plot( x, y )

    ax = fig.add_subplot( gs[1, 0] )
    ax.plot( x, z )

    ax = fig.add_subplot( gs[2, 0] )
    ax.plot( y, z )

    plt.show()
```

This is the image I get: [image: This is the image I get]

I think I am either missing a simple bug or my understanding of the problem is incorrect.

EDIT: adding the expected results:
[image: expected result]
and problem statement:
[image: problem statement]

Comment: What have you tried to test for validity? You could for example numerically compute $\dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z}$ from the output data and check if the ODE is satisfied. You could also test your Runge-Kutta implementation on a simpler ODE of which you know the exact solution. Furthermore your python code is incomplete (it lacks the imports) so a potential answerer can not easily execute it themselves. Also what exactly makes you think that there might be an issue in the code?

Comment: I have added the imports, thanks for the suggestion. I have validated at least the integrator by implementing the Lorenz equations, and I get the correct picture. I will try to validate the derivatives, is it just a matter of using finite differences on the output data and verify that it's close the analytical solution? I know the output for the ABC flow is incorrect because the book has a picture of the expected output, my solution is completely different.

Comment: You compute $\dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z}$ using finite differences from your output data and compare it to the right hand side of the ABC equation (using your output data for $x,y,z$). After all you are trying to create output data for which the two are equal (approximatly). Also it might be a good idea to include the picture from your book and perhaps the instructions as well (if they arent too long).

Comment: I have added the problem statement and description from the book. I'll validate the derivatives in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution looks correct. Note that the reference pictures display the solutions modulo $2\pi$, as also the equations are invariant under shifts by $2\pi$. In plotting these reduced solutions one has to make sure to cut out the jumps at the wrap-arounds.

See https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29823/poincare-map-for-arnold-beltrami-childress-magnetic-field-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792164/how-to-implement-a-method-to-generate-poincar%c3%a9-sections-for-a-non-linear-system for other discussions of this topic.

---

With the paramters and initial point used, you get one tunnel among the many stable looking components. Using 20 random initial points gives the projections

[image: projections on coordinate planes]

One can get "true 3D" with a stereoscopic image. There will be slight irritations as matplotlib does not implement sufficient 3D Z-ordering.

[image: stereogram]

and finally the section with the plane $\{y=0\}$

[image: intersection with xz plane]

Comment: Thanks, I was reading [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231891929_Chaotic_Streamlines_in_the_ABC_Flows) which also mentioned the module $2\pi$, but I wasn't sure how to implement it. Going back to the book, they did mention a Poincaré section but I hadn't connected the dots (pun intended).

Comment: It is one strategy to not connect the dots, just compute enough points by having a small step size or using dense output interpolation, then mod $2\pi$ and just plotting the dots should still produce recognizable lines. A second variant is to compute segments, ending one segment when the $\pm \pi$ boundaries are violated and starting a new segment with the reduced point. Then plot the curves for each segment, cropping the view field if desired.